# Is there any way to use the X Windows System on MS-Windows?

Tags: windows, xorg

I want to learn the X Windows System (Don't Ask Me Why Or How). And I can't because I am using Windows XP.I have looked at a few X Servers and Emulators but they either aren't open-source , are in their alpha stages or have been abandoned. Is there any way to run the X Windows System properly on MS-Windows? Any good server? Any library? Anything?

Comment: Use Virtualization, such as VWWare Server or some such program, and install an OS that uses the X Windows System

Comment: Why does not being open source disqualify an X server from being "anything" or "properly"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I know these two - but I do not have any experience using them

http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

http://x.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ubuntu inside a virtual machine. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is an open source virtual machine that is quite good.

Comment: The PC i am using for development only has like 40 GB of hard disk space most of which is occupied by Compilers and SDKs , so another OS is not an option.

Comment: The Ubuntu install disk is only 700 MB, so the VM can't take more than  2-3 GB at most I think.